# Как в PhpStorm работать с двумя репозиториями svn одновременно

Tags: phpstorm, svn

Мне нужно заливать файлы то на один репозиторий, то на другой

Comment: вариант добавить второй remote вам не подходит?

Comment: в phpstorm я использую svn не из консоли. вы можете подсказать, как сделать это не из консоли?

Comment: или скажите, как в svn через терминал добавить remote

Comment: RTFM https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-subversion-repository-location.html but beware of different UUIDs

Comment: спасибо @LazyBadger, я добавил несколько. но как указывать куда я хочу выгрузить?